# ckfinder how do I check what version I have?

Tags: ckfinder

I'm working with ckeditor and ckfinder.
does anyone know how to check what version of ckfinder I have?
is there a javascript of php code for this?
in CKEditor I can add a button 'about' in the toolbar.
but I can't find it in ckfinder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the source or can contact someone that does, it looks like your current version number can be found in ckfinder/changelog.txt.

There are a list of changes in each version, your current would be the first/largest version number listed.

Comment: I figured it out: I made sure that I have my full toolbar, there is a question mark button, that shows the current version.
see this demo: http://ckeditor.com/demo